# Multi tenant and site with Experience Analytics

Tags: sxa, experience-analytics, multisite

I have a Question about Experience Analytics.

If I create a new tenant and site should it automatically add the newly created site in the Filters dropdown in the Experience Analytics Dashboard?

Currently, I don't see it in the dropdown filter. Is there something else that I need to do for it to show or do I just need to wait until interactions are recorded and a new report gets generated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything for this, it works OOTB and collects data and shows it on the `Experience Analytics` dashboard.

There could be many reasons for analytics data not showing, there is a knowledge base article that describes the processes for troubleshooting the most frequent issues with `Analytics` data in the `Sitecore Experience Database installation`.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445

You need to run a few pages on the browser of the newly created site and it will start collecting the data and show it on the `Experience Analytics` dashboard. It may take a couple of minutes to show the data.

So create a few pages and run them and it will start collecting the data if everything works perfectly with your `Sitecore` instance. Otherwise, follow the above article to troubleshoot the issues and correct them.

Finally, I would say, if it still does not work then you can check logs and get some context to find out the actual error coming with your Sitecore solution.

Hope this information helps you to start.